# Need help on randomizing a function (on C) that return null if a value in the vector is 0

Tags: c, function, pointers, null

I'm having problems trying to get the vector return null if the rand gives a 0, and return the highest number in the vector in case it doesn't random a 0. I think I might be screwing things up on the main() since I'm just returning the result of the funcion, but I don't know if that's a problem.

```
double* maximo(double* vetor, int tamanho)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        tamanho = rand() % 99999999;
    }

    if (tamanho = 0) {
        printf("NULL");
    }
    else {
        printf("%f", &tamanho);
    }

        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return maximo;
}
```

I'd really like to have some help on this, since I'm feeling like a retarded seal trying to get it working.

Comment: Turn compiler warnings on

Comment: @user3562717, it appears that you wish to call 'maximo()' from 'main()'.  However, no parameters are supplied to the call.  If the code compiles, it appears that (perhaps) the address of the 'maximo()' function is returned, without actually calling it.  Can you edit your code [above] to add parameters?  (ie: 'return maximo(/*vector*/, /*tamanho*/);'

Comment: `if (tamanho = 0)` looks buggy. `printf("%f", &tamanho);` not sure how `%f` and a pointer can go together.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Thanks for the tip on the return, help me getting a little focus on the problem and fixing it.

Comment: @xiaomao I found the double with pointer weird too, but my teacher sent us these and it's working, so I'll leave it just like this until it stops working...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to fix here:

1: Calling the function

```
return maximo;
```

This is just returning the address of the function to the operating system. You need to call the function using something like:

```
double *result = maximo(vetor, tamanho);
```

2: It is unclear what maximo is supposed to do with its parameters - it doesn't use the vetor and it immediately replaces the value of tamanho. I assume it is supposed to be a array and a size of that array. You need to have an array and a size to pass it.

```
double vetor[4] = { 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0 }
int tamanho = 4;
double *result = maximo(vetor, tamanho);
```

3: You need to do something with the result of the call. This is where you want your printf.

```
if (result == NULL)
    printf("Not Found\n");
else
    printf("Found %ld", *result);
```

4: In your function you need to save `tamanho` for when you loop around the `vetor`. So don't assign a random number to it. Use another variable.

```
int myRand = rand()%99999999;
```

5: The chances of `rand()%99999999` being zero are **very very low**. Maybe pick a smaller number. Like 10.

6: When you test the random number in an if test, do not use single `=` as that is assignment. Instead of:

```
if (tamanho = 0)
```

use

```
if (myRand == 0)
```

7: if the random number is 0 then you want to `return NULL`. If it is not zero, you need to loop over the array and find the highest number, then return the **pointer** to that number. Try writing this code by yourself and asking another question if you need.

8: when you use `rand` you should call `srand(time(NULL))` once in your main function. Otherwise you will get the same random number sequence all the time.